# Remove Wiishlist Button

Tags: magento2

[image]

i want if some one add wishlist item then this hear will become remove button form addto wishlist how we can acheive this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want.
So do you want to remove the wishlist button from the Category page?

Answer (score 0):

First you need override file from vendor folder to in your theme. which path is given below please check.

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

**To**

`app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

If this file is already in your theme so just add the below tag for category page only.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
```

After that flush cache and check.